Does Dragon Ball Daima happens after or before Vegeta, Gohan and Piccolo got their new transformations?
After Dragon Ball Super, Vegeta, Gohan and Piccolo got new transformations. Vegeta got a transformation in the manga called Ultra Ego, and Gohan and Piccolo got a transformation in the movie called Gohan beast and Orange Piccolo respectively. Meaning we never saw these transformations in an anime Dragon Ball series.
Does Dragon Ball Daima happens after or before Vegeta, Gohan and Piccolo got their new transformations? Do we have chances to see them in these series?

Daima occurs before the start of Super. You may note that Gohan is absent during the events; that's because he's still in highschool along with Videl and they are not yet married. If you recall, the beginning of super was a party where it was revealed that Gohan and Videl had a child (that was the gimmick for Shenron's wish, with required 5 other Saiyans).
Meanwhile in Daima, Majin Buu was just defeated, as we saw in the first episode.
